# Firebase Cloud Functions Async for big tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am making an app where I use the firebase cloud functions to add content to users after following another user, the problem I have is that sometimes there are many documents that are read and added to other collections. Could someone help me check what I have wrong with this function, please.

I have seen that they use runTransaction for different tasks but I don't know if it is necessary here, I need the function to add the documents to the subcollection.

Thanks!

```
exports.userFeedUpdateOnFollow = functions.firestore.document("/following/{currentUid}/user-following/{uid}").onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  const currentUid = context.params.currentUid;
  const uid = context.params.uid;
  try {
    const snapshot = await db.collection("posts").where("uid", "==", uid).where("contentForFeed", "==", true).orderBy("stats.timestamp", "desc").limit(20).get();
    const promises: any[] = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const postId = doc.id;
      const post = doc.data();
      if (post) {
        const timestamp = post.timestamp;
        const config = post.config;
        const uid = post.uid;
        const writeResult = db.collection("users").doc(currentUid).collection("following-feed").doc(postId);
        const dataToSet = {"timestamp": timestamp, "config": config, "uid": uid, "from": "user"};
        promises.push(writeResult.set(dataToSet));
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  } catch (err) {
    functions.logger.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any glaring issues, but you could rewrite it into a single [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) instead of sending off up to 20 write requests.

Comment: Thanks, But if the function reads and writes more than 2,000 documents, what is the best way to do it? I ask because I want to do it in the most efficient way.